# Invalidate entire object store TTL upon purge in Vanish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using the Vasnish cacher with TTL set to 10 seconds and grace period to 60 seconds.

I would like to be able to invalidate the TTL (set it to expired) upon an event. When this event happens, I know my backend has changed, I want vanish to update my cache, but I do not mind to keep updating it in the background.

Is there a way, I can somehow trigger TTL invalidation for the entire store and not just on one object, while keep the grace period intact?

Answer (score 0):

### Use bans to match multiple objects

You could use the `ban()` function in VCL and issue the following ban expression:

```
obj.status != 0
```

This will match every object whose status code is not zero. Every object should match this expression.

### The VCL code

In terms of VCL the function call would look like this:

```
vcl 4.1;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "EMPTY") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return (synth(405));
        }
        ban("obj.status != 200");
        return (synth(200,"Cache emptied"));
    }
}
```

Please adjust the ACL to match the IPs or subnets you would be calling the ban from.

I opted for a request method named `EMPTY`, but it could be anything you want.

### Triggering the EMPTY call

To trigger the event, you could call Varnish with the `EMPTY` request method. This would then empty the cache.

This would be a potential `cURL` call to do this:

```
curl -XEMPTY http://localhost
```

### More information

To learn more about bans in Varnish, have a look at the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/ban/